# When and why did rugby union change the number of reserves?

Tags: rugby-union

In the 2011 world cup teams fielded 22 players each and in the 2015 world cup fielded 23 players. 
When was this changed? Is there a reason given by world rugby as to why this decision was made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a change designed to reduce the number of matches which were forced to have uncontested scrums due to not having appropriate players available - rugby union scrummaging is a *highly* technical activity, and having players not skilled in it attempt it is not allowed due to the risk of injuries involved if the scrum collapses.

[The original change to the Laws happened in 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090822203000/http://www.irb.com/newsmedia/mediazone/pressrelease/newsid=2033086.html). However, at that point the option to allow 23 players, which  had to include 6 front-row players, was an option only for national and cross-border matches. It explicitly did not apply to international matches at that stage, which is why the 2011 World Cup was played with 22 man squads.

I can't find the exact date when 23 player squads were allowed in international rugby, but the change had obviously happened by 2015.